# livebooting ubuntu on Acer Aspire 15 laptop just loop restarts into Grub

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my Winbdows AMD Acer Aspire 5 15 laptop but when I select "Try or install Ubuntu" (or "Ubuntu (safe graphics)") in the Grub menu the laptop simply reboots and ends up at the same Grub menu. Before the the Grub menu appears I momentarily see a log that reads "error: file /boot not found"

I'm livebooting off a USB burnt using balenaEtcher and I've tried both the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and 23.10 images and both have the same issue. I've turned off SecureBoot and fast boot in the BIOS and I've turned off Windows 11 hibernate by running "powercfg.exe /hibernate off" in CommandPrompt.

In the grub CLI I've explored the filesystem and the USB partition 1 (hd0,gpt1) is mounted as root and running `ls /` returns `boot/ boot.catalog casper/ install/ md5sum.txt pool/ preseed/ ubuntu` which I believe means the correct partition as been mounted as the rootfs. I've additionally tried manually running the commands found at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` without the `quiet` argument to the kernel but I get the same result without any extra output. I've tried using 2 different USB sticks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: what model do you specifically have? Maybe take a look at this other post: https://askubuntu.com/a/1497825/1621824

Comment: Has the USB successfully booted on any computer ever?